# Removing subdomain with bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Suppose i have a variable called `$subdomain`that contain `test.google.com` .How can i strip the subdomain to get `google.com`and store it in a variable called $maindomain.

Comment: It depends what assumptions you are willing to make. Do you specifically want to remove `test.`: `maindomain="${subdomain#test.}"`, or the first part up to and include the `.`: `maindomain=${subdomain#*.}`? What is the scope of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please indicate more possible cases: what if `google.com` alone? what if `hello.google.co.uk`, what if...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
maindomain=${subdomain#[[:alpha:]]*.}
```

will remove "test." or any other similar prefix, before the first point.

Better answer, as we can have multiple subsubdomains:

```
maindomain=$(expr match "$subdomain" '.*\.\(.*\..*\)')
```

It keeps only the trailing `xxxxxx.xxx` part of a domain.

Answer (score 8):

One subdomain

```
maindomain=${subdomain#*.}
```

with more subdomains

```
maindomain=$(sed 's/.*\.\(.*\..*\)/\1/' <<< $subdomain)
```

Remove URI if there is one

```
maindomain=$(sed 's/.*\.\(.*\..*\)/\1/' <<< ${subdomain%/*})
```

Comment: For this particular case, yes. However, I'm assuming that there may be more to it.

Comment: @TomFenech Will work for any case ,without a URI, in the format specified by OP. So should work for any valid web address and will just remove everything before the first `.`.

Answer (score 2):

```
> subdomain=1.2.3.4.5
> IFS=. read -ra __ <<< "$subdomain"
> IFS=. eval 'maindomain="${__[*]:(-2)}"'
> echo "$maindomain"
4.5
```

Another:

```
> IFS=. read -ra __ <<< "$subdomain"
> IFS=. eval 'maindomain="${__[*]:(-3)}"'
> echo "$maindomain"
3.4.5
```